# Xamarin.Android TextView with hyperlink, intercept onclick intent

Tags: android, xamarin, hyperlink, mime

Got a `TextView` with following content

```
hallo <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">click me</a>.`
```

Setting the `textView.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance` works fine and makes the link clickable, opens correctly in browser by default.

Now the question: How can I write a `Service` or 
    `IntentService` to intercept links with other (custom) mime type than http. How to do it using Xamarin-Attributes?

When I change the href attribute to i.e. "myscheme", I get

```
    Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=myscheme (has extras) }.
```

Is it possible using `IntentFilter` to  make the service kick off once the hyperlink is activated? I already tried many combinations which I will not post now though.

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful : https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Comment: Ok. so it seems to work once I use the IntentFilter with an Activity. According to spec supposed to work with Service as well,although discouraged. In case somebody get it working with Service or IntentService, plese let me know.